# How to access properties and multiple values in an awaited object?

Tags: vb.net

I have a class which contains some properties I need to access the values of in another file.

```
Public Class ReturnValues
    Public Property result As String
    Public Property resultBank As String
    Public Property resultAddressMatch As String
End Class
```

I call my async function and also create a new instance of my object

```
Dim results As ReturnValues = New ReturnValues()

Public Shared Async Function x(ByVal sUserID As String) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Object)
```

It goes ahead and makes a call to an external api and I get my results and store them as an object

```
results.result = data.data.attributes.result
results.resultBank = data.data.attributes.bank_account_match
results.resultAddressMatch = data.data.attributes.name_and_address_match

Return results
```

In my other file I await the result. I can see when debugging that the awaited result contains a property of Result that has the three pieces of data I need to access.

```
Await result
```

I'm not quite sure where I go from here as I can't put a . after the results and access anything relevant.

I did try to explicitly convert it to a list and access them this way but no such luck.

```
            Dim list = CType(result, Object())

            sResult = list(0)

            sResultBank = list(1)

            sResultNameAddressMatch = list(2)
```

How can I get the 3 results out of my result object?

Comment: I don't really understand what the issue is. If you have an `Async` function declared `As Task(Of ReturnValues)` then awaiting that method results in a `ReturnValues` object so you access the properties of that object like you would any other. You seem to be trying to create an issue where there is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
dim R as ReturnValues = await result
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to using `Async` and `Await` is that you have the following transformations:

On the side of the asynchronous routine, `Function x As SomeType` turns into `Async Function x As Task(Of SomeType)`.

On the side of the caller:

```
Dim y as SomeType
'...
y = x()
```

Turns into:

```
Dim y as SomeType
'...
y = Await x()
```

If you weren't writing this as async code, I hope you wouldn't be trying to turn something of type `ReturnValues` into a `List`.  You should write the client as if the function were not async, and then just insert `Await` in the call.  The rest will work as you would expect.